# How to make buttons inside columns equal in height on all devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My Bootstrap columns are equal in height no matter the size of the device (computers, tablets, phones, etc.) thanks to JavaScript's MatchHeight.

But the problem is that I also want to make the buttons inside them equal in height despite different amount of text above them. I've tried min-height, margin-bottom (aren't responsive). How can I achieve this? With bootstrap somehow, or js, or something but it's important for aesthetics!

EDIT: This is what I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOlns.png
Buttons stay the same no matter what!

```css
#section4 .divider-fullwidth {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#section4 .lastdivider {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#section4 .box {
  margin: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5% 8%;
}

#section4 .btn {
  font-size: .9em;
  padding: 5% 4%;
  width: 100%;
}

#section4 .innerBox {
  min-height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background_section4">
  <div id="section4" class="container">
    <div class="row intro">
      <h2>ESCOGE TU PLAN</h2>
      <p>El precio influye en el tipo y número de actividades que organizaremos, pero te aseguramos que todas son extraordinarias.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row columns">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>
            <span style="font-weight: 100;">ZZZ</span><span style="color: #e5e874; font-weight: 800;">basic</span>
          </h4>
          <p>
            <span style="font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;">29</span><span style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">€</span> adulto / 14€ niñ@
          </p>
          <div>
            <p>El plan perfecto para iniciarte como. Date un capricho y pasa un día diferente.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="divider-fullwidth">
          </div>
          <div class="innerBox">
            <p>
              <strong>Algunos planes sorpresa que han hecho otros Zurpraisers:</strong>
            </p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>Salida en catamarán + Snorkel en mar abierto</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Visita Bodegas + Cata de vinos + Brunch entre viñedos</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Circuito SPA privado + Copa de cava + Menú degustación</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Menú degustación fusión cocina japonesa y mexicana</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="divider-fullwidth lastdivider">
          </div>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg" href="">QUIERO MI</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>
            <span style="font-weight: 100;">ZZZ</span><span style="color: #f99584; font-weight: 800;">plus</span>
          </h4>
          <p>
            <span style="font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;">59</span><span style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">€</span> adulto / 29€ niñ@
          </p>
          <div>
            <p>Solo para espíritus aventureros con hambre de descubrir nuevas y emocionantes experiencias.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="divider-fullwidth">
          </div>
          <div class="innerBox">
            <p>
              <strong>Algunos planes sorpresa que han hecho otros:</strong>
            </p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>Excursión guiada en moto acuática + Menú degustación estilo Mediterráneo</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Masaje relajante de chocolate blanco natural + Jacuzzi de cacao + Circuito SPA privado + Curso de cata de vinos</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Barranquismo guiado + Menú degustación</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="divider-fullwidth lastdivider">
          </div>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg" href="">QUIERO MI</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box lastBox">
          <h4>
            <span style="font-weight: 100;">ZZZ</span><span style="color: #7ed9c3; font-weight: 800;">premium</span>
          </h4>
          <p>
            <span style="font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;">99</span><span style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">€</span> adulto / 49€ niñ@
          </p>
          <div>
            <p>¡Vamos a lo grande! Una combinación de actividades exclusivas para ocasiones especiales.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="divider-fullwidth">
          </div>
          <div class="innerBox lastInnerBox">
            <p>
              <strong>Algunos planes sorpresa que han hecho otros Zurpraisers:</strong>
            </p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>Vuelo en parapente biplaza + Visita bodegas + Cata de vinos + Menú degustación con maridaje exclusivo</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Puesta de sol en velero + Degustación de ostras con cava + Cena romántica bajo las estrellas</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Conducción de Ferrari en circuito + Bautismo de buceo + Menú degustación</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="divider-fullwidth lastdivider">
          </div>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg" href="">QUIERO MI</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a picture of what you want to do? And also please provide how it's looking right now. Is it the same as the snippet I added?

Comment: Done! sorry! I hope that image I have included in my op helps you guys understand what I want it to look like! also snippet isn't really how it looks now. I have 3 columns, inline, and they are the same height indeed. The problem is the buttons inside them, which aren't equally aligned like in the image above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution, I assume ,this is what you are looking for.

```
.box{
  position: relative;
  height:500px;
}
.btn{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  width: auto; //You can adjust the width accordingly
}
```

You can adjust the height of your div accordingly.

---

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 440px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: .9em;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row columns">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h4>
        <span style="font-weight: 100;">ZZZ</span><span style="color: #e5e874; font-weight: 800;">basic</span>
      </h4>
      <p>
        <span style="font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;">29</span><span style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">€</span> adulto / 14€ niñ@
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>El plan perfecto para iniciarte como. Date un capricho y pasa un día diferente.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divider-fullwidth">
      </div>
      <div class="innerBox">
        <p>
          <strong>Algunos planes sorpresa que han hecho otros Zurpraisers:</strong>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Salida en catamarán + Snorkel en mar abierto</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Visita Bodegas + Cata de vinos + Brunch entre viñedos</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Circuito SPA privado + Copa de cava + Menú degustación</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Menú degustación fusión cocina japonesa y mexicana</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="divider-fullwidth lastdivider">
      </div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-primary" href="">QUIERO MI</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h4>
        <span style="font-weight: 100;">ZZZ</span><span style="color: #f99584; font-weight: 800;">plus</span>
      </h4>
      <p>
        <span style="font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;">59</span><span style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">€</span> adulto / 29€ niñ@
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>Solo para espíritus aventureros con hambre de descubrir nuevas y emocionantes experiencias.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divider-fullwidth">
      </div>
      <div class="innerBox">
        <p>
          <strong>Algunos planes sorpresa que han hecho otros:</strong>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Excursión guiada en moto acuática + Menú degustación estilo Mediterráneo</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Masaje relajante de chocolate blanco natural + Jacuzzi de cacao + Circuito SPA privado + Curso de cata de vinos</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Barranquismo guiado + Menú degustación</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="divider-fullwidth lastdivider">
      </div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-primary" href="">QUIERO MI</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="box lastBox">
      <h4>
        <span style="font-weight: 100;">ZZZ</span><span style="color: #7ed9c3; font-weight: 800;">premium</span>
      </h4>
      <p>
        <span style="font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;">99</span><span style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">€</span> adulto / 49€ niñ@
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>¡Vamos a lo grande! Una combinación de actividades exclusivas para ocasiones especiales.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divider-fullwidth">
      </div>
      <div class="innerBox lastInnerBox">
        <p>
          <strong>Algunos planes sorpresa que han hecho otros Zurpraisers:</strong>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Vuelo en parapente biplaza + Visita bodegas + Cata de vinos + Menú degustación con maridaje exclusivo</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Puesta de sol en velero + Degustación de ostras con cava + Cena romántica bajo las estrellas</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Conducción de Ferrari en circuito + Bautismo de buceo + Menú degustación</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="divider-fullwidth lastdivider">
      </div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="">QUIERO MI</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Padding given to `.box` is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you! However this only works for computers, as soon as I make it smaller in size, the buttons stop having the same height. :/

Comment: Got what the problem is. You will have to provide height for the `box` class.

Comment: Thank you I will try this when I get home and will let you know if it's working on all devices thanks man

Comment: It works and it's responsive but now part of the buttons are positioned outside their boxes, and the dividers are gone... man how can this be so difficult to achieve? i'm not asking for the moon lol. Thanks for your help anyway! I just don't know what to do :/